# Can't move objects created by archimesh into a collection folder

Tags: collections, archimesh-add-on

When I move objects into a collection by drag and drop, or by <kbd>M</kbd> key, it does not move the whole structure. I tried *Select Hierarchy*, but there are still objects left, and I am not sure how to remove it. I tried to search but without any success.

I would like to move it into collections to do a cleanup and make it easier to use.

It seems like a duplication, but if I remove the item in the root it deletes it in the collection as well. I tried to click on *Unlink* but it deletes it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It was because those objects had parent. So I had to remove it or change it to the correct parent. Quite a lot of manual work, but works.